# Doctrine ORM returns strings only

Tags: php, orm, types, casting, doctrine

When I have my DQL query from a table in my database and return `var_dump()` for example the ID of the row it'll be type of `string`, despite the fact it is an unsigned INT(10) in the DB, which is very annoying when I want to `echo json_encode($row->toArray());`. Every integer will be wrapped in quotation marks.

How can I instruct Doctrine to cast types properly and not leave them "as is" like described here: http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DC-769

Comment: Why is it important that they are of a specific type?

Comment: It is important for using them in a REST-API accessed by many different customers and programs. Not "typehinting" them as a float or int can lead to errors. And can you tell the difference between a phone number and a reference ID without having its datatypes?

Comment: What DB are you using in the back end?  I've noticed that with PDO, when you fetch data from a Postgres database the driver will attempt to use appropriate PHP data types for the columns, but with MySQL it always returns strings. I don't know if this is relevant to your problem, but I thought it might be helpful for you.

Comment: Yes thats the exact problem I'm mentioning ;) My question is: can Doctrine solve this by converting the string type from MySQL (which is the DB I'm actually using) to its real datatype representation of PHP deposited in each DB column. Phone numbers and Datetimes of course would be returned as string as there is no uniform object representation in PHP, but IDs will become int and so on.

Comment: btw. the datatypes for each column are disposited in the Doctrine Models as well, so it won't be a problem to cast each element. But I couldn't find any flag or config to instruct Doctrine to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the Doctrine version I was actually using (v1.2.8 installed via APT) was too old to handle this feature. When I updated to Doctrine 2 my described problem was solved.

You should consider an update if you have the same issue, but be aware of the changes that were made from Doctrine1 to Doctrine2! Migration could take some time.